why does my HTML to ADF script exiting with code 0?
I am trying to create a script that will convert HTML into Jira's ADF format. When I try to test the script using Visual Studio 2019 it just gives this output - "The program '[36520] HTMLtoADF.exe' has exited with code 0". I am not too familiar with c# or visual studio so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Here is the script I have created below:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Sample HTML content
        string htmlContent = "<p>Hello, <strong>world!</strong></p>";
        // Convert HTML to ADF
        string adfResult = ConvertHtmlToAdf(htmlContent);

        // Output the ADF result
        Console.WriteLine("Converted ADF:");
        Console.WriteLine(adfResult);
    }

    static string ConvertHtmlToAdf(string htmlContent)
    {
        // Load HTML content into an HtmlDocument for parsing
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

        // Create a list to store ADF nodes
        List<JObject> adfNodes = new List<JObject>();

        // Convert HTML nodes to ADF
        foreach (var htmlNode in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            var adfNode = ConvertHtmlNodeToAdfNode(htmlNode);
            adfNodes.Add(adfNode);
        }

        // Create an ADF document with the collected nodes
        var adfDocument = new JObject(new JProperty("version", 1), new JProperty("type", "doc"), new JProperty("content", adfNodes));

        // Return the ADF content as a JSON string
        return adfDocument.ToString();
    }

    static JObject ConvertHtmlNodeToAdfNode(HtmlNode htmlNode)
    {
        // Map HTML node to ADF node
        switch (htmlNode.NodeType)
        {
            // If the HTML node is an element (e.g., <p>, <strong>)
            case HtmlNodeType.Element:
                return ConvertHtmlElementToAdfNode(htmlNode);
            // If the HTML node is a text node
            case HtmlNodeType.Text:
                return ConvertHtmlTextToAdfNode(htmlNode);
            // Handle other node types as needed
            default:
                return new JObject();
        }
    }

    static JObject ConvertHtmlElementToAdfNode(HtmlNode htmlElement)
    {
        // Map HTML element to ADF element
        switch (htmlElement.Name.ToLower())
        {
            // If the HTML element is a paragraph (<p>)
            case "p":
                // Convert the <p> element to an ADF paragraph node
                return new JObject(
                    new JProperty("type", "paragraph"),
                    new JProperty("content", new JArray(ConvertHtmlNodesToAdfNodes(htmlElement.ChildNodes))));
            // If the HTML element is a strong emphasis (<strong>)
            case "strong":
                // Convert the <strong> element to an ADF text node with strong emphasis
                return new JObject(
                    new JProperty("type", "text"),
                    new JProperty("text", htmlElement.InnerHtml),
                    new JProperty("marks", new JArray(new JObject(new JProperty("type", "strong")))));
            // Add more cases for other HTML elements as needed
            default:
                return new JObject();
        }
    }

    static JObject ConvertHtmlTextToAdfNode(HtmlNode htmlText)
    {
        // Map HTML text to ADF text
        // Create an ADF text node with the content of the HTML text node
        return new JObject(new JProperty("type", "text"), new JProperty("text", htmlText.InnerHtml));
    }

    static List<JObject> ConvertHtmlNodesToAdfNodes(HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodes)
    {
        // Convert a collection of HTML nodes to ADF nodes
        var adfNodes = new List<JObject>();
        foreach (var htmlNode in htmlNodes)
        {
            // Convert each HTML node to its equivalent ADF node
            var adfNode = ConvertHtmlNodeToAdfNode(htmlNode);
            adfNodes.Add(adfNode);
        }
        return adfNodes;
    }
}


Working fine

exited with code 0 means your program  did  the job without error.
There should be a black command window when running the program.
But if you are using  C# .NET Framework console project, the black window will close quickly after completion (less than one second).
So, you can add Console.ReadKey(); on the last line of main to prevent the window from closing.
static void Main()
{
    // Sample HTML content
    string htmlContent = "<p>Hello, <strong>world!</strong></p>";
    // Convert HTML to ADF
    string adfResult = ConvertHtmlToAdf(htmlContent);

    // Output the ADF result
    Console.WriteLine("Converted ADF:");
    Console.WriteLine(adfResult);
    Console.ReadKey();//added 
}

